# Error: ENOENT: no such file or directory, stat '/app/client/build/index.html'

Tags: node.js, reactjs, heroku

My App works perfectly fine but whenever I try to deploy it to Heroku it keeps getting this error.

index.js:

```
const express = require('express');
const mongoose = require('mongoose');
const cookieSession = require('cookie-session');
const passport = require('passport');
const bodyParser = require('body-parser');
const keys = require('./config/keys');
require('./models/User');
require('./models/Asset');
require('./models/Episode');
require('./config/passportConfig');

mongoose.connect(keys.mongoURI, { useNewUrlParser: true });

const app = express();

app.use(bodyParser.json());
app.use(
    cookieSession({
        maxAge: 30 * 24 * 60 * 60 * 1000,
        keys: [keys.cookieKey]
    })
);

app.use(passport.initialize());
app.use(passport.session());

require('./routes/authRoutes')(app);
require('./routes/assetsRoutes')(app);

if(process.env.NODE_ENV === 'production') {
    app.use(express.static('client/build'));

    const path = require('path');
    app.get('*', (req, res) => {
        const index = path.join(__dirname, 'client', 'build', 'index.html');
        res.sendFile(index);
    });
}

const PORT = process.env.PORT || 5000;
app.listen(PORT, () => {
    console.log(`server is up at port ${PORT}.`)
});
```

index.html is actually there but Heroku seems to never find it
[image: Screenshot from the project.]

> please ignore this is just a filler because StackOverflow won't let me
>   post a question without details but I don't have many details to add.
>   :)